# selenium - extracting value from cell (td)

Tags: java, selenium, html-table, row, cell

I'm writing a Java test using cellenium, in order to validate the correctness of data I'm trying to extract the values of the table cells, although all cells have different values and meaning the `<td>` of all cells look the same and have the same attributes like so:

```
<td onclick="show_data('2','2','rowDetails.php','myID','434b2410aef9e61d6237dbbe562689a9b84','644');">2</td>
```

the naive solution would be to extract all tag `<td>` and then go by index.

Is there a better way?

Comment: are you using `webdriver`? and Can you provide the sample code you have?

Answer (score 0):

If your elements have no unique identifier then the common way to solve your problem is by fetching all the TD elements and loop over them. This is something you already seem to be aware of, as you're describing this as: *extract all tags and then go by index.*

However, your provided example does contain a unique identifier, namely the property of the `onclick` attribute. By using CSS selectors, don't use XPath, you can do a select based on the property (the value) of the `onclick` attribute. This should help you to narrow down the elements you are looking for.

For list of CSS Selectors see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp